# Fixing a user ID value in a computed field (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal-7

I have a content type in Drupal 7 for creating an article. I want a computed field, called 'author', that stores the user ID of whoever created the article, but which doesn't change to the user ID of anyone who subsequently edits the article. Therefore this, won't do because 'author' will re re-set according to the last user who saved the article:

```
  $entity_field[0]['value'] = $user -> uid;
```

The user ID of the originator, if you like. I thought the following, placed in the computed code section of the content type settings, would work: if 'author' doesn't contain anything then populate it with the user ID, if it does then do nothing.

```
if (!isset($entity -> field_author['und'][0]['value']) {
  global $user;
  $entity_field[0]['value'] = $user -> uid;
}
```

It doesn't work. My question: does this not work because I'm testing the existence of a value in a field of a record that has not yet been created? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: The user id does not change when a node is updated. So there is no need for a computed field like I thought I needed.